# Flutter How to change value of variable within setstate function?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to change the value of the selected date and save it to the variable and print it to the screen like below images :

[image]

when i click ok i want to save it on the hint properties inside of my custom texform widget so it will change accordingly when user choose certain date:

[image]

the problem when i tried to change the value of variable within the state code so i have my snippet below from my custom class:

```
class MyInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final Widget? widget;
  const MyInputField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title,
      required this.hint,
      this.controller,
      this.widget})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15, fontFamily: "Lato", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
            height: 52,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    readOnly: widget == null ? false : true,
                    autofocus: false,
                    cursorColor: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                    controller: controller,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Loto",
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: hint,
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: context.theme.backgroundColor,
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                widget == null
                    ? Container()
                    : Container(
                        child: widget,
                      ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and i want to change the hint variable which is string to adjust accordingly what the user is choose

this is the variable that i want to change dynamicly _selectedDate:

```
DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
```

full code snippet:

```
class AddTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTaskPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddTaskPageState createState() => _AddTaskPageState();
}

class _AddTaskPageState extends State<AddTaskPage> {
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
        toolbarHeight: 80,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onTap: () {
            return Get.back();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Add Task",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontFamily: "Lato",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              MyInputField(title: "Title", hint: "Enter Your Title"),
              MyInputField(title: "Note", hint: "Enter Your Note"),
              MyInputField(
                title: "Date",
                hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
                widget: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.date_range,
                    color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _getDateFromUser();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
    );
  }

  _getDateFromUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickerDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2015),
        lastDate: DateTime(2121),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: child ?? Text(""),
          );
        });
    if (_pickerDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _pickerDate = _selectedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print("It's null something wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

and at the bottom i already using if else conditonal statement within **setState** function but it doesn't work how to change the _current selectedDate value to _PickerDate value ?

```
if (_pickerDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _pickerDate = _selectedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print("It's null something wrong");
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't you replace ```_pickerDate = _selectedDate;``` with ```_selectedDate = _pickerDate;```?

Comment: whoa yes man,i didn't notice that i need to change the selecteddate not the pickerdate.
thank for the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the answer is just simply by [Ehsan Askari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10901093/ehsan-askari)

> shouldn't you replace `_pickerDate = _selectedDate;` with `_selectedDate = _pickerDate;`?